# stacked bar chart with color sum

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to visualize the following information in the form of a stacked bar chart with x axis having different boroughs, and the bars are colored with totals of different types of injuries

Text representation of data is here

BOROUGH
tpedinjury
tcycinjury
tminjury

BRONX
3975
959
11197

BROOKLYN
8781
3978
25822

MANHATTAN
6607
3164
8698

QUEENS
5893
1993
21092

STATEN ISLAND
653
101
3528

[image]

Comment: Welcome to stack Overflow! Instead of an image that requires us to retype your data, please use `dput` to make a text representation of the data that we can cut and paste from your question.

Comment: Updated the ask with the data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, get the data into a data.frame:

```
data <- data.frame(BOROUGH = c("BRONX", "BROOKLYN", "MANHATTAN", "QUEENS", "STATEN ISLAND"),
           tpedinjury = c(3975, 8781, 6607, 5893, 653),
           tcycinjury = c(959, 3978, 3164, 1993, 101),
           tminjury = c(11197, 25822, 8698, 21092, 3528))
```

Here's what that looks like:

```
> data
        BOROUGH tpedinjury tcycinjury tminjury
1         BRONX       3975        959    11197
2      BROOKLYN       8781       3978    25822
3     MANHATTAN       6607       3164     8698
4        QUEENS       5893       1993    21092
5 STATEN ISLAND        653        101     3528
```

For plotting ease, we'll want it in long format. I like to use `gather()` from the `tidyr` package for that, but there are several other functions that also do the same thing, so take your pick.

```
data <- gather(data, "injurytype", "number", -BOROUGH)
```

Now the data look like this:

```
> data
         BOROUGH injurytype number
1          BRONX tpedinjury   3975
2       BROOKLYN tpedinjury   8781
3      MANHATTAN tpedinjury   6607
4         QUEENS tpedinjury   5893
5  STATEN ISLAND tpedinjury    653
6          BRONX tcycinjury    959
7       BROOKLYN tcycinjury   3978
8      MANHATTAN tcycinjury   3164
9         QUEENS tcycinjury   1993
10 STATEN ISLAND tcycinjury    101
11         BRONX   tminjury  11197
12      BROOKLYN   tminjury  25822
13     MANHATTAN   tminjury   8698
14        QUEENS   tminjury  21092
15 STATEN ISLAND   tminjury   3528
```

Use `geom_bar(stat = "identity")` with `fill = injurytype` to get a stacked bar plot.

```
ggplot(data, aes(x=BOROUGH, y=number, fill = injurytype)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

[image: stacked barplot]

Answer (score 0):

The `barplot` function will do this, but you need to reshape the data first.

```
Dat2 = t(df[,2:4])
colnames(Dat2) = df$BOROUGH
barplot(Dat2, col=rainbow(3), ylim=c(0,40000))
legend("topright", legend=names(df)[2:4], 
    pt.bg=rainbow(3), pch=22, bty="n")
```

[image: Barplot of Injuries]